# Porting C++ server to cloud

Tags: tcp, network-programming, cloud, tcplistener

I have multiple traditional servers and thousands of users connect to these servers. My server software is written in C++ listening these users on TCP socket and I've defined my own protocol (above TCP). Server code is written such that it is capable of handling client to client communication (for e.g. instant messaging) no matter which client is connected to which server machine. It's typical traditional server farm scenario.

Now when I want to switch this to cloud what changes do I need to do? I am new to cloud and all I know is cloud provider gives us APIs to communicate with cloud instance/DB and we now do not need to worry about actual server instances running behind (load balancing etc it is all taken care by cloud infrastructure).

1. Can single cloud instance could handle thousands (or say millions) of connections?
2. My server code is written in C++ and when I want to switch to cloud is it going to be obsolete? and do I need to develop my server from scratch using cloud APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > My server code is written in C++ and when I want to switch to cloud is it going to be obsolete? and do I need to develop my server from scratch using cloud APIs?

What you have is an application currently being run on your in house hwardware. With cloud the hardware and OS infrastructure is provided by cloud provider. You need to take your application to cloud and run as-is(almost). If for example, currently you run in your application on CentOS 7, you can create a instance of CentOS 7 in the cloud, and your C++ application should run without issues. Cloud provider "facilitates" with their APIs. It does not enforce application re-write with their APIs. So, there is no need to develope from scratch.

> > Can single cloud instance could handle thousands (or say millions) of connections?
> >     Depends on the dimensions ( w.r.t to processor, memory, n/w throughput, etc) of the instance that you to use from the cloud provider.